# Sharepoint opens documents twice

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, office-2013

We are running Sharepoint 2010 and a user has a problem that whenever they click on a document within Sharepoint it opens the document twice. I have made sure that IE is opening in 32 bit mode, made sure the SharePoint OpenDocuments Class is enable and the Office Document Cache Handler is enabled, but it still happens! Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.